# Angularjs ui-router: Rewrite location with default parameter resolved

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have multiple nested states. Let's say:

```
departments:
/departments/:idDepartment

departments.group:
/group/:idGroup

departments.group.category:
/category/:idCategory
```

Each state has a resolve to retrieve his data, prerequisites. BTW, I use this workaround to use the parent states resolved data in the child states resolve (https://gist.github.com/MattWalker/6106393)

When the user goes to /processes I redirect him to /departments//group//category/ so he can see the default department with the default group and default category. I don't want him to select a department then a group then a category. I want to show him right away a view with default values.

It works but here is my question. Once the default values have been found and the view is shown, how can I have the url location display something like

```
/departments/1/group/23/category/2
```

instead of

```
/departments//group//category/
```

Thanks

Comment: So, `$state.transitionTo("departments.group.category", { idDepartment: 1, idGroup: 23, idCategory: 2 })` doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! Yes it would work (by adding some $q.all to get all the infos from the API) and if I was in a controller. But the thing is that /departments/x/group/y/category/z  is the main entry point of the application. People goes to / and I forward it to /departments//group//category/ using $urlRouterProvider. I'm not in a controller yet and $urlRouterProvider.when doesn't support promises.

Comment: Then I guess you need to handle your redirects in a different way...